# howto fix composer.json in forked symfony bundle

Tags: symfony, github, composer-php, fork

I'm trying to install `symfony-cmf/routing-auto` version 2.0.0-RC1 , it requires  `jms/metadata:1.5.*`  which is working under Symfony 2x.

My current project works on Symfony 3.3.x which makes this bundle unable to install, so I made a fork on github, changed req. to `jms/metadata:1.6.*`
and added one line:

`"replace": "symfony-cmf/routing-auto:2.0.0-RC1",`

in order to test if it will work and I used in console:

`composer require mkoniarz/routing-auto:dev-master`

but then I got error:

> Reading composer.json of mkoniarz/routing-auto (dev-master)           Skipped branch dev-master, Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

What else I should fix to get this fork installed by composer?

PS my composer is up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

always check composer.json:

```
composer.phar validate
```

then commit if valid :)

error was in "replace" line:

```
"replace": "symfony-cmf/routing-auto:2.0.0-RC1",
```

should be:

```
"replace": { "symfony-cmf/routing-auto":"2.0.0-RC1" },
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove the composer.json file ? I'd an similar error, i think it can be resolve your problem.

Or you should to try :

```
composer require symfony-cmf/routing-auto
```